# How to remove all the pages from page stack in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I know how to remove the old pages from page stack.

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

This will remove the last entry from the page stack.

But I want to remove all the pages form the page stack.
If I click the clear button all the page should be cleared.
Please let me know any idea to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Clearing backstack in NavigationService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241529/clearing-backstack-in-navigationservice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you clear your NavigationService BackEntry without getting Exceptions:

```
while(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

Comment: Hi @Verdesrobet.. I am getting this error message:- **Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CanGoBack' cannot be used like a method.**

Comment: **while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();**  This is Working..!! And this also working:- **while (this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)         
                this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();**

Comment: Hi @verdesrobert.. Thanks for your answer.. Please edit the answer. from **CanGoBack()** to **CanGoBack**..

Comment: @NewDeveloper it was removed by someone else

Answer (score 0):

This is the other way to remove all pages from page stack:

```
while( NavigationService.BackStack.Count()>0)
      {
         this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
      }
```

Comment: Hi @Pradeep.. There is no Count Property in BackStack.

Comment: Ok..friend this property is in wp8 sdk i think you r using wp7 as this question tag